# Nested if statement with While loop stuck

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The code is for multiple choice question. If the answer is incorrect, the user should try until they find the right answer. When the answer is correct, there is no problem, but if it is wrong then it gets stuck, and it is keep saying "Your answer is incorrect!". What should I do?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Question 1");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("What is 2+2?");
        System.out.println("A. 2");
        System.out.println("B. 4");
        System.out.println("C. 6");
        System.out.println("D. 8");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char getAnswerFromUser = input.next().charAt(0);
        char answer = 'B';

        boolean isAnswerTrue = false;

     
        while(!isAnswerTrue) {
            if(getAnswerFromUser == answer ) {
                System.out.println("Your answer is correct!");
                    isAnswerTrue = true;
            } else{
                System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect!");
                isAnswerTrue = false;
            }       
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You read `getAnswerFromUser` before your loop, and you do not update it inside your loop.

Comment: If the answer is incorrect, you just need to let the user enter a new answer and assign it to `getAnswerFromUser` inside the loop

Comment: Besides writing programs, you should also learn how to use your IDE's debugging features, e.g. single-stepping your program. Then you'll see that, after the initial input it never again gets to a statement where it tries to read a fresh input, but keeps looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually getting a new answer from the user inside your loop.  You are only getting it once, in the line where you define the variable getAnswerFromUser.  You need to actually get a new answer.  I suggest putting it into a separate method to keep that step clean from the step where you use that answer.